# Energy and power of a signal via Fourier

Tags: homework-and-exercises, signal-processing

It is asked to evaluate the energy and power of the signal

$$x(t)=10\cos(100t+30°)-5\sin(220t-50°)$$

Since it is periodic, I need to find

$$\int _{-\infty}^\infty |x(t)| dt\quad \text{ and }\quad \frac{1}{T}\int_{-T}^T |x(t)|^2 dt$$

Where $T$ is the period of $x(t)$ (which is 18). By Parseval's theorem, we know the energy is conserved when we do a fourier transform and I was trying to use it (but I couldnt). What is the best way of evaluating those integrals?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use Parseval's thm rather than direct integration?  What do you mean by "couldn't":  you got different answers than direct integration?  you couldn't do the integral?

Comment: you need to understand the difference between *"finite power signals"* and *"finite energy signals"*.  (a non-zero, finite power signal has infinite energy.)  also, this would be better submitted to the [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating your integral over infinite time, you will get infinite energy. The nice thing about average power is that you can individually estimate it for each component - and that as such it only depends on the amplitude (and not, for example, on the phase). If you like, you could prove this to yourself.

In this case you have one wave with an amplitude of 10, and another with an amplitude of 5. For a cosine wave with an amplitude A, the average (RMS) power is 0.5 A$^2$ - so in this case I am pretty sure I can estimate the average power in my head as being 62.5

Trying to map all this to Parseval's theorem is going the long way around.